# Rails Segmentation Fault on Mac OSX with RVM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-snow-leopard, rvm

When creating a new rails app, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:799: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

All the rails files appear to be generated, but the error above is still there. Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks to me like a problem with LLVM GCC, try with GNU GCC.

The easiest way to do that is to install osx-gcc-installer and reinstall ruby:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

EDIT2: it is also possible to use gcc-4.2 available via HomeBrew/MacPorts, install CommandLineTools and follow instructions from `rvm requirements`.

EDIT 1: I've googled around and come across this http://www.seqmedia.com/2012/05/08/frustrations-abound-rvm-vs-macports-and-the-bug-segmentation-fault/ - and I remember it was already mentioned to me `openssl` in OSX is broken, the easiest way to check it would be:

```
rvm get stable
rvm autolibs enable
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Comment: Thank you, mpapis. I installed osx-gcc-installer and reinstalled ruby, but still the same error.

Comment: check `rvm ruby-1.9.3-p194 do ruby -rrbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['CC']"` - it has to point to `gcc-4.2`, if it does not please try `rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-gcc=gcc-4.2`

Comment: Hi mpapis, thanks again for responding! Here is the result from the check: $ rvm ruby-1.9.3-p194 do ruby -rrbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['CC']"

A RVM version 1.13.4 (master) is installed yet 1.13.4 (stable) is loaded.
Please do one of the following:
  * 'rvm reload'
  * open a new shell
  * 'echo rvm_auto_reload_flag=1 >> ~/.rvmrc' # for auto reload with msg.
  * 'echo rvm_auto_reload_flag=2 >> ~/.rvmrc' # for silent auto reload.

Comment: So... I did rvm reload. Then your check again: $ rvm ruby-1.9.3-p194 do ruby -rrbconfig -e "puts RbConfig::CONFIG['CC']"
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2    Still getting the same error?

Comment: I believe you're correct... there seems to be an issue with openssl and OSX. Your approach may work and I found this early today before I saw your response: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4050    rvm pkg install openssl
rvm remove 1.9.3-p125
rvm install 1.9.3-p125 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr   This worked for me. Thank you for helping me out, mpapis!

Comment: Of course, I installed the latest 1.9.3 version p194, not p125.

Answer (score 16):

I googled around for this problem and found the following magic incantations:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Sorry to not link back to a source but I can't remember which website had the winning formula. The gist of it is that ruby links against a bad version of openssl so doing it this way makes rvm install its own version of openssl and link ruby against that.

Answer (score 2):

Managed to fix it like this:

**Update rvm:** rvm get head
**Install the required libraries:** rvm requirements run
**Reinstall 1.9.3:** rvm reinstall 1.9.3

Runs for a while and seems really clean

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this bug by removing my gloabally installed gems and reinstalling the Heroku toolbelt.  Not sure why but it worked for me.