# Error while creating a new app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

Environment - rvm ruby - rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby

I am trying to create a new rails app but it's failing with this exception http://pastebin.com/cNKDuFVc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the version of openssl in OSX is broken, you need to install it manually, either with HomeBrew, MacPorts, SMFramework or just RVM, here is my answer to similar question with proper fix:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540282/497756

Comment: That seems to be working. But I am not sure. Can you check if this output is ok http://pastebin.com/gxi0BJkW

Comment: looks quite good, but make sure you do not have `-n` or `--user-install` in output of `gem env` to avoid any surprises

Answer (score 1):

Do you use macports? If yes this may help http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/01/fixing-a-segmentation-fault-in-ruby-193/

Comment: I might have. I have worked on Sproutcore earlier and I had all the ruby tools. I uninstalled some. How to determine. If I run bundle command I get "Could not locate Gemfile". Does this mean I have macports?

Comment: No. Macports is a tool for installing programs.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps [Segmentation Issue](http://blog.55minutes.com/2012/01/fixing-a-segmentation-fault-in-ruby-193/)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new rails app with the following

```
rails new app_name --skip-bundle
```

It looks like bundler is seg-faulting, so if skipping bundler works, then I would try reinstalling bundler, if you still have issues, you may have to reinstall that version of ruby.

What version of OS X and XCode did you install rvm with? The ruby issues may be caused by XCode

Comment: --skip-bundle worked. So is this still a valid app or something is missing. I am on Snow Leopard. I didn't use XCode command line tools because its installer is no longer available for Snow Leopard. I have used this https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer

Comment: The app is valid, but you will not be able to run it locally, as your ruby build is probably messed up. You can build ruby fine with XCode 4.1. I would try reinstalling RVM and Ruby so that you don't run into segmentation faults.

Comment: I can't install xcode 4.1. That would mean I have to upgrade to Mountain Lion. I will try installing command line tools for Xcode 3 and see if I can compile ruby with that

Comment: My mistake, you should be able to install Xcode 3.2.6, which has the command line tools included in the installer.  Installing 3.2.6 will allow you to install rvm