# Ruby on Rails Eventmachine segfault

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm

Having some seriously strange problems with my rails install, any help much appreciated.

It all began when I ran `bundle clean --force` hoping to solve some gem issues with a project. I then ran bundle install, but things were never the same. First, I had a weird `[BUG] cross-thread violation on rb_gc()` error when running `rails s`. After running `gem clean` I managed to move on to a new error:

```
bundle exec rails s
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/rubyeventmachine.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0034 p:-17535289580530 s:0105 b:0105 l:000104 d:000104 TOP   
c:0033 p:---- s:0103 b:0103 l:000102 d:000102 CFUNC  :require
c:0032 p:0010 s:0099 b:0099 l:000091 d:000098 BLOCK  /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
c:0031 p:0071 s:0097 b:0097 l:000096 d:000096 METHOD /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
c:0030 p:0019 s:0092 b:0092 l:000091 d:000091 METHOD /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
c:0029 p:0150 s:0087 b:0087 l:000086 d:000086 TOP    /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:66
c:0028 p:---- s:0085 b:0085 l:000084 d:000084 FINISH
c:0027 p:---- s:0083 b:0083 l:000082 d:000082 CFUNC  :require
c:0026 p:0010 s:0079 b:0079 l:000071 d:000078 BLOCK  /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
c:0025 p:0071 s:0077 b:0077 l:000076 d:000076 METHOD /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236
c:0024 p:0019 s:0072 b:0072 l:000071 d:000071 METHOD /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251
c:0023 p:0083 s:0067 b:0067 l:000066 d:000066 TOP    /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin.rb:7
c:0022 p:---- s:0065 b:0065 l:000064 d:000064 FINISH
c:0021 p:---- s:0063 b:0063 l:000062 d:000062 CFUNC  :require
c:0020 p:0026 s:0059 b:0059 l:000039 d:000058 BLOCK  /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68
c:0019 p:---- s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 FINISH
c:0018 p:---- s:0054 b:0054 l:000053 d:000053 CFUNC  :each
c:0017 p:0091 s:0051 b:0051 l:000039 d:000050 BLOCK  /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
c:0016 p:---- s:0045 b:0045 l:000044 d:000044 FINISH
c:0015 p:---- s:0043 b:0043 l:000042 d:000042 CFUNC  :each
c:0014 p:0046 s:0040 b:0040 l:000039 d:000039 METHOD /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55
c:0013 p:0021 s:0036 b:0036 l:000035 d:000035 METHOD /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119
c:0012 p:0089 s:0032 b:0032 l:000031 d:000031 TOP    /Users/yuletide/code/txtyourcity_rails/config/application.rb:7
c:0011 p:---- s:0030 b:0030 l:000029 d:000029 FINISH
c:0010 p:---- s:0028 b:0028 l:000027 d:000027 CFUNC  :require
c:0009 p:0016 s:0024 b:0024 l:000015 d:000023 BLOCK  /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53
c:0008 p:---- s:0021 b:0021 l:000020 d:000020 FINISH
c:0007 p:---- s:0019 b:0019 l:000018 d:000018 CFUNC  :tap
c:0006 p:0702 s:0016 b:0016 l:000015 d:000015 TOP    /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50
c:0005 p:---- s:0012 b:0012 l:000011 d:000011 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0010 b:0010 l:000009 d:000009 CFUNC  :require
c:0003 p:0061 s:0006 b:0006 l:000df8 d:0008c8 EVAL   script/rails:6
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:000df8 d:000df8 TOP   

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
script/rails:6:in `'
script/rails:6:in `require'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in '
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
/Users/yuletide/code/txtyourcity_rails/config/application.rb:7:in `'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin.rb:7:in `'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:66:in `'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------

   See Crash Report log file under ~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter or
   /Library/Logs/CrashReporter, for the more detail of.

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: script/rails

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/enc/encdb.bundle
    2 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/enc/trans/transdb.bundle
    3 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
    4 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/rbconfig.rb
    5 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    6 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    7 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
    8 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
    9 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/pathname.bundle
   10 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/pathname.rb
   11 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb
   12 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/etc.bundle
   13 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/config_file.rb
   14 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb
   15 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb
   16 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb
   17 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb
   18 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb
   19 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/psych.bundle
   20 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/stringio.bundle
   21 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/node.rb
   22 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/stream.rb
   23 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/document.rb
   24 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/sequence.rb
   25 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/scalar.rb
   26 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/mapping.rb
   27 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes/alias.rb
   28 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/nodes.rb
   29 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/streaming.rb
   30 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych/visitors/visitor.rb
   31 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0/strscan.bundle
... snip ...
2.0.2/lib/simple_form/wrappers/builder.rb
  629 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/simple_form-2.0.2/lib/simple_form/wrappers/many.rb
  630 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/simple_form-2.0.2/lib/simple_form/wrappers/single.rb
  631 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/simple_form-2.0.2/lib/simple_form/wrappers/root.rb
  632 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/simple_form-2.0.2/lib/simple_form.rb
  633 /Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

[1]    1577 abort      bundle exec rails s
```

gem env

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.21
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-02-16 patchlevel 125) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ayule/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/ayule/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/ayule/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-11
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/ayule/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125
     - /Users/ayule/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

rvm seems to be working fine:

```
code/txtyourcity_rails(master) ☸ which ruby
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
code/txtyourcity_rails(master) ☸ which rails
/Users/yuletide/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rails
```

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing - have you build your ruby using clang/LLVM, ruby is not yet ready for it, the bug should be reported most likely to bundler / ruby.

To fix follow instructions from my other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540282/497756 to similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what caused it initially, but managed to get the error to go away by upgrading to 1.9.3-p194 with rvm, creating a .rvmrc, and then running `bundle install`

Comment: looks even more like llvm issue, you can check what compiler was used for ruby with `ruby -rrbconfig -e 'system "#{RbConfig::CONFIG["CC"]} --version"'` if it contained `llvm` or `clang` - then you know why it was failing and it might fail again - just later, Ruby is not yet ready for clang, better compile with `gcc-4.2` to avoid random failures