# RVM issue with Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, rvm

I can install any Ruby versions on a Mac running Mountain Lion

I have made sure Brew Doctor is all good.

When I run ie rvm intall 1.9.3-head I get the following.

```
From git://github.com/ruby/ruby
 * branch            ruby_1_9_3 -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Copying from repo to src path...
ruby-1.9.3-head - #autoreconf
ruby-1.9.3-head - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-head - #compiling 
Error running 'make', please read /Users/lee/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-head/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
lee$ mate /Users/lee/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-head/make.log
```

This is the make.log http://pastie.org/private/wt48jlhlng9tgbdgqap8q

Please can anyone advise. It looks like MD5 is the issue ?? Im not expert at command line so any help would be fantastic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10540282/497756

the main point is:

```
rvm pkg install openssl
```

and then:

```
rvm reinstall 1.9.3
```

Comment: Thank's for that. I am 99% sure I already tried that but it worked this time. TY

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

- Update Xcode, get the version that will work with Lion and run the command again.
- Install using:

> rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang

Install GCC 4.2 and try:

> rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=gcc-4.2

Hope one of these will work.

Comment: First one I got:  Error running 'make', please read /Users/leesmith/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-head/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
clang: error: unsupported option '--with-libyaml'
Ruby 'ruby-1.9.3-head' was built using clang - but it's not (fully) supported, expect errors.  Second one just failed

Comment: aghh.. I saw this in the past, I'm sure. All I remember it's was a problem with the compiler for 1.9. Did you get the chance to try the last one?

Comment: Yea I ran both. This is really getting me down. Be at it all day. Would be easier to go back to Lion but I dont want to !