# ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, osx-mountain-lion, sudo

I have checked all the other similar answers and none was exactly like mine, neither did any of those solutions work for me.

`gem environment` and `sudo gem environment` give the same result:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.5.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/ava/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

`rvm -v` : `rvm 1.22.3`

`ruby -v` : `ruby 1.8.7`

`OSX 10.8.4`

`echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/home/ava/.rvm/bin:/home/ava/bin`

`gem install <gem-name>` gives

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
```

whereas I am able to install the same via sudo. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

As per comments and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469530/getting-ruby-1-8-7-installed-on-mountain-lion-10-8), I ran following:

`rvm implode` and then re installed the stable version.
`rvm install 1.9.3` or any other ruby installation fails with

```
Error running '__rvm_make -j24',
please read /home/ava/.rvm/log/log/1378418790_ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

`make.log`

```
    [2013-09-05 22:06:48] make
current path: /home/ava/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194
command(2): make -j24
        CC = gcc
        LD = ld
        LDSHARED = gcc -shared
        CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Werror-implicit-function-declaration  -fPIC
        XCFLAGS = -include ruby/config.h -include ruby/missing.h -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT
        CPPFLAGS =   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I./include -I.
        DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-soname,libruby.so.1.9
        SOLIBS = -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm
compiling main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling dmyencoding.c
compiling version.c
compiling miniprelude.c
compiling array.c
compiling bignum.c
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
compiling complex.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling enum.c
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling load.c
compiling proc.c
compiling file.c
:
:
:
In file included from ossl.h:213,
                 from ossl_pkcs5.c:5:
openssl_missing.h:71: error: conflicting types for ‘HMAC_CTX_copy’
/usr/local/include/openssl/hmac.h:102: error: previous declaration of ‘HMAC_CTX_copy’ was here
openssl_missing.h:95: error: conflicting types for ‘EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy’
/usr/local/include/openssl/evp.h:459: error: previous declaration of ‘EVP_CIPHER_CTX_copy’ was here
make[2]: *** [ossl_pkcs5.o] Error 1
In file included from ossl.h:213,
                 from ossl_x509req.c:11:
:
:
:
```

Comment: what is the output of `rvm list` and `which ruby`? Basically there are two ruby 1.8 installed in your computer and you need to used the one installed at /home/ava/.gem/ruby/1.8 instead of /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8. Setting rvm to use the right ruby should solve the issue.

Comment: rvm list `ext-ree-1.8.7-2011.12` which ruby `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

Comment: try : `rvm remove ext-ree-1.8.7-2011.12` . `rvm install 1.8.2` . rvm use 'the new ruby version installed' --default

Comment: `rvm install 1.8.2` fails with `There is no checksum for 'http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.8/ruby-1.8.2.tar.gz' or 'ruby-1.8.2.tar.gz', it's not possible to validate it.`

Comment: I don't think 1.8.2 is supported on anything any more. It hasn't been kept up to date, and it won't compile without a lot of manual fixes. After all, it was released in 2004. Why would you want 1.8.2, anyway?

Comment: I was just following the above comment. I want to install 1.8.7 but getting the error as mentioned in the updated answer.

Comment: Sometimes, deleting the `$GEM_HOME` directory fixes this kind of issues.

Answer (score 125):

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.

1. Install RVM (optional)
2. Set the gem folder in your shell resource file. I.e. `.zshrc`, `.bashrc` etc

```
export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"
```

3. Install you gem `gem i LIBRARY_NAME`

Comment: Work for me on MacOsX High Sierra.

Comment: For people using RVM, this is a great solution for safely using system Ruby. Don't forget also add `$HOME/.gem/bin` to your path as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50361633/574981 uses `~/.ruby` here it uses `~/.gem`
is there a *official* or more common or preferred way?

Comment: I cant install LIB, what is it anyway? didn't install LIB and it works perfectly.

Comment: Works on Catalina too. Just put `export GEM_HOME="$HOME/.gem"` into Terminal

Comment: @AlexanderSaenko in case, put into Ternimal, it will make temporary solution during shell session. If you need permanent – set the command in your shell config.

Comment: @StefanKrüger don't know, but if talk goes about gem, I am sure that `~/.gem` folder is more appropriate.

Comment: Works on Monterey with Ruby ruby 2.6.8

Comment: Works on MacOS Ventura 13.1 .Install "gem I cocoapods"

Answer (score 60):

To resolve the error:

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>       You don't have write permissions into the /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.

the following solution worked for me:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: Using sudo to install a ruby gem? Not sure that's necessary, much less smart--in terms of security, stability, etc.

Comment: [**Never install dependencies with `sudo`!**](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Best-Practice%3A--Never-install-gems-with-sudo)

Comment: I don't know why this answer has a lot of votes, the best practice is never install gems with sudo.

Comment: Simply adding a `~/.gemrc` files as suggested by another answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25716203/5362795) did it for me, no `sudo` required.

Comment: @Nagev This solved the issue for me. I'm on Catalina.

Answer (score 47):

Your *global* (system-wide) config file probably has the [`--no-user-install`](http://guides.rubygems.org/command-reference/#gem-install) flag set.  Create/edit your local `~/.gemrc` file and append the following line(s):

```
:gemdir:
    - ~/.gem/ruby
install: --user-install
```

**Note**
The actual directory for the `gemdir` option will vary depending on your system/desire; it may or may not be needed, but it's probably better to designate the desired installation directory within your `home` folder (`gemdir`) than to assume it'll be taken care of by itself.

The [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ruby#Installing_gems_per-user_or_system-wide) has some useful/well-organized information pertaining to this.

---

### chruby

Alternatively, similar to the `rvm` solution already suggested, you can try using [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) to maintain, configure, and use local versions of `ruby`.  To install additional versions of `ruby`, however, you need to use [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install).

```
$ brew install chruby ruby-install
$ ruby-install ruby 2.4.0

$ echo "source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo "chruby ruby" >> ~/.bash_profile

# Do this to select the default alternative ruby installation, assuming
# there is no other version installed.
$ chruby ruby

## Otherwise, list the available ruby versions installed, and select
$ chruby
ruby-2.3.0
ruby-2.4.0

$ chruby ruby-2.4.0
```

From the project's README:

> Changes the current Ruby. Features
>
> ```
> Updates $PATH.
>     Also adds RubyGems bin/ directories to $PATH.
> Correctly sets $GEM_HOME and $GEM_PATH.
>     Users: gems are installed into ~/.gem/$ruby/$version.
>     Root: gems are installed directly into /path/to/$ruby/$gemdir.
> Additionally sets $RUBY_ROOT, $RUBY_ENGINE, $RUBY_VERSION and $GEM_ROOT.
> Optionally sets $RUBYOPT if second argument is given.
> Calls hash -r to clear the command-lookup hash-table.
> Fuzzy matching of Rubies by name.
> Defaults to the system Ruby.
> Optionally supports auto-switching and the .ruby-version file.
> Supports bash and zsh.
> Small (~100 LOC).
> Has tests.
> ```
>
> Anti-Features
>
> ```
> Does not hook cd.
> Does not install executable shims.
> Does not require Rubies be installed into your home directory.
> Does not automatically switch Rubies by default.
> Does not require write-access to the Ruby directory in order to install gems.
> ```
>
> Requirements
>
> ```
> bash >= 3 or zsh
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much ! The `chruby` worked for me and I was finally able to `gem install bundler` again on my Mac without this nasty PermissionDenied-Error that the Ruby-version mismatch caused !! Thanks :).. Do you know, in general, if it is a good idea to update your Ruby version on MacOS ? And if yes, do you prefer `chruby` or `ruby-install` ??

Comment: you can use `ruby-install` to install newer versions of ruby.  Then, use `chruby` to switch to the newer version.  No need to deal with system-wide versions of ruby for your projects.

Comment: The `~/.gemrc` editing solution worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 26):

If you have installed `rvm` as the root user, then you must `sudo` to install anything.

You can install `rvm` in user-mode as a regular user, in which case everything is stored in your home directory and no `sudo` is required.

If you are not committed to this particular install, type `sudo rvm implode` and start over.

Comment: @IulianOnofrei This is to remove RVM, not install dependencies. If it was installed with root, it must be uninstalled with root.

Comment: "sudo gem install xcodeproj" works on me
Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

**Macbook M1** and newer  :

Open Terminal
`curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Reopen Terminal

```
rvm install ruby-3.1.1 
rvm use ruby-3.1.1 
rvm --default use 3.1.1
```

Then this installed cocoapods as expected

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: sudo gem install cocoapods worked but bundle install not working

Comment: `rvm --default use <ruby version>` works for me, because it overrides the system installed ruby due to which I was getting Gem::FilePermissionError.

Answer (score 8):

If you have installed rbenv & facing this error, below answer will help (this is how it worked for me)

Issue:

```html
$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

*DO NOT USE SUDO*

1. check the rbenv versions

```html
$ rbenv versions
* system (set by /Users/user/.rbenv/version)
  2.3.8
```

Here, you can see, by default it selected system. change it to your ruby version.

```html
$ rbenv global 2.3.8
$ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.3.8 (set by /Users/user/.rbenv/version)
```

Then try installing the bundler, it will work:

```html
$gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
Fetching: bundler-1.17.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.17.3
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.17.3
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.17.3
Done installing documentation for bundler after 5 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Comment: Seems like this is required too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67115739/129202

Answer (score 6):

The "write permissions" errors and `Gem::FilePermissionError` mentioned here are due to an improperly configured Ruby environment. You should never need to use `sudo` to install gems, no matter how many times you see it as an accepted answer on Stack Overflow. [Here's why](https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/why-you-should-never-use-sudo-to-install-ruby-gems/?utm_source=stackoverflow).

At a high level, setting up a proper Ruby development environment on a Mac involves six steps:

1. Install Homebrew (which also installs the prerequisite Apple command line tools)
2. Install a Ruby manager (such as chruby, rbenv, asdf, RVM) - most of these can be installed with Homebrew
3. Configure the Ruby manager by adding the appropriate lines to your shell file (`~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`) - each manager will have instructions for doing this, and this is a typical step that people miss
4. Restart the terminal (or open a new tab) for the shell changes to take effect - another step that is often overlooked
5. Install a specific version of Ruby using the Ruby manager
6. Switch to that version of Ruby using the Ruby manager

My personal preference is [chruby](https://github.com/postmodern/chruby) with [ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install). For more details and a script that can automate this whole process, check out my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54873916/928191

Comment: As general context for `rbenv` users, this can happen if you haven't installed a version (terminal `open ~/.rbenv/versions/` should have a folder for each installed version), or if you haven't set the version you wish to use globally/locally (e.g., `rbenv global 3.1.0`). Other potential causes are failing to configure your shims path.

Answer (score 4):

assuming that rvm is installed you could do something like:

```
$ rvm install 2.1.1
$ rvm @global do gem install compass
```

No need to do sudo.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `rbenv`, it's possible that you forgot to enable it with something like:

```
> rbenv init
# Load rbenv automatically by appending
# the following to ~/.zshrc:

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if you chose to perform a multi-user install of rvm, you must add each user to the rvm group via

```
usermod -a -G rvm <USERNAME>
```

Relevant info from rvm's [FAQ](https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting#sudo)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error yesterday when I tried to install rails using following command.

```
$ gem install rails -v 4.2.3
```

Prior to this I had installed Ruby Environment Manager (rbenv), but the following command failed to add the if-eval to bash profile.

```
$ echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> -/.bash_profile
```

So, I looked into this and found out that the current directory reference - was the problem for the above command to fail. I changed it to ~ and successfully ran the below command

```
$ echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After this I was able to install the rails gem successfully (without needing to do sudo)

Answer (score 0):

I run into a similar problem on my Mac while trying to install watchr package

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)

Somehow running sudo every time I need to install a package felt excessive. I have rbenv installed so I set global ruby version like this

```
rbenv global 2.6.5
```

Then simply installed the package I wanted. In my case the command is

```
gem install watchr
```

Answer (score 0):

ok after trying all the different solutions above, none of them worked for me. So for those who will encounter it in the future please know this.
the solution could have  nothing to do with cocoa pods but more with Xcode new versions. as you update the new version you need to agreed with the new terms and conditions. you can do so directly in the terminal.
Run :
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
and than:
sudo xcodebuild -license
than press space till you arrive at the button and finally type agree
From than can try again to add cocoapods with simply :
gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

If you have just installed `rvm`, and you are getting error like this

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.

remember to call

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to make sure that gems are installed in ~/.rvm

Then you can simply

```
rvm use 2.6.6
gem install yourgem:2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to update my ruby to the newest version use
brew ruby install

and after I got my latest ruby version , gem install rails will work

Comment: Can you explain yourself clearer?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.
For example if you are running this from a Jenkins perspective things dont work the same way as when  firing up a bash shell and giving gem or bundle instructions. I got the same error when Jenkins but failed to realize that Jenkins has his own way of figuring out the PATH so things may not work well there unless you find the proper jenkins config field to fill in related information for .. wherere is ruby for example. Otherwise you may end up issuing symbolic link commands to link where the machine understands the executables..

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem: `sudo`

I was using `asdf` version manager. I was trying to install `cocoapods` for Flutter. Originally I had `sudo` installed the gem, then I read in the documentation that I should install without `sudo` for version managers, so I tried uninstalling it and then reinstalling it without `sudo`, but was receiving this error:

> ```
> ╰─❯ gem install cocoapods                                                                  
> Successfully installed cocoapods-1.11.3
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
>     You don't have write permissions for the /Users/coder/.asdf/installs/ruby/3.1.0-dev/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0+0/doc/cocoapods-1.11.3 directory.
> ```

### The Fix

I navigated to the directory listed above and deleted the empty folder.

Then I was able to run: `gem install cocoapods` without any errors.

Unfortunately `flutter doctor` still seems to be upset about the availability of cocoapods

### The Fix for `flutter doctor`

It seems that it wasn't liking Ruby v3.2, and it was odd because `asdf` showed that I had v3.1 which was confusing. I decided to install Ruby v2.7.4 then just `gem install cocoapods` now `flutter doctor` is all green

Answer (score 0):

As Mac user the below was straight forward

```
❯ /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
❯ brew install ruby
```

##### Option (1) adding the path if you are using zhs

```
❯ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
❯ source ~/.zshrc
```

##### Option (2) adding the path if you are using bash

```
❯ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
❯ source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score -1):

You probably don't have write permissions to somewhere along that path, (most likely /usr/local/lib), you need to change the location of your RVM storage in order to not need sudo