# Rails Installation Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am getting the below error while installing Rails I am getting the below error after I run gem install rails

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

Comment: I'm still learning CLI Linux, but I think this means your user does not have [CHMOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) permissions for that directory. You'll either need to use `root` or `sudo`, as mentioned in the ansewr

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried typing:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

Similar Quesion:
[ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599889/error-while-executing-gem-gemfilepermissionerror)