# How do I install ruby gems on Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

How do I install RubyGems on my Mac?

I tried to run `$ gem install rubygems-update` with no luck. It returns:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
```

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: though this command may succeed if you use `sudo`, in the long run it'll be easier if you use a version manager like rbenv or rvm.

Comment: You can only run `gem` from command line if you have RubyGems installed. So you may have to install manually.

Comment: For MacOS Majave, here's a good guide: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave

Comment: I found this helpfull https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599889/error-while-executing-gem-gemfilepermissionerror

Answer (score 131):

I would highly suggest using a package manager and a Ruby Environment Manager.

On Mac, you can run:

```
brew update
brew install ruby

# If you use bash
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bash_profile 

# If you use ZSH:
echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.4.1_1/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.zprofile
```

However, I suggest using an Environment Manager for Ruby.

You have [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) and [RVM](https://rvm.io/). IMO go for rbenv:

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build

# bash
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile  

# zsh
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zprofile
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zprofile  

# list all available versions:
rbenv install -l

# install a Ruby version:
rbenv install 2.4.1

# set ruby version for a specific dir
rbenv local 2.4.1

# set ruby version globally
rbenv global 2.4.1

rbenv rehash
gem update --system
```

Comment: Good point +1.  That is why I am asking questions, I got the last command working by running it in a new shell (without running it as sudo). I am now trying to get my first package oauth installed with the newest gems 2.4.1, getting some odd LoadError [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/288148/loaderror-in-installing-packages-such-as-oauth-with-ruby-gems-why).

Comment: the first part of this answer works fine if you also immediately run the `export` command in the current shell. I have no interest in installing `rbenv` or `rvm`; I just need access to a public gem temporarily. Thanks!

Comment: On OSX, don't forget to log out of your OSX session and then log back in for the changes to your bash profile to take effect. So you don't have to search why this doesn't work and endup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940736/rbenv-not-changing-ruby-version).

Comment: I added this to my $PATH so I don't wonder what broke when ruby gets updated: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/$(ls -1rt /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/ | tail -1)/bin

Comment: Everybody is telling me to install rbenv. I don't care about Ruby, I can do that. But does it affect how I use Ruby and run the commands in the gem (which are what I actually care about)?

Answer (score 18):

One more variant is to use brew-gem.

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/brew-gem

https://github.com/sportngin/brew-gem

Just copy/paste from the documentation:

> brew install brew-gem
>
> **Usage**
>
> `brew gem install heroku`
>
> To install a specific version: `brew gem install heroku 3.8.3`
>
> To install using a brew installed ruby(/usr/local/bin/ruby): `brew gem install heroku --homebrew-ruby`
>
> And with a specific version: `brew gem install heroku 3.8.3 --homebrew-ruby`
>
> To upgrade: `brew gem upgrade heroku`
>
> To uninstall: `brew gem uninstall heroku`
>
> To check information: `brew gem info heroku`
>
> Note: Installed gems are listed in brew list with prefix of *gem-*, like *gem-heroku*.

Comment: Worked for me - no `sudo` required!

Answer (score 12):

After installing cocoapods as Tulon suggested the thing which worked for me was passing the `--user-install` flag to the gem install command e.g

```
gem install rubygems-update --user-install
```

from https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#sudo-less-installation

Answer (score 4):

You may have to install manually in which case (as per the [official website](https://rubygems.org/pages/download#formats)):

1. Go to the [official website](https://rubygems.org/pages/download#formats) and download the zip file
2. Unzip the file in a directory.
3. Then go to the directory in your terminal and run: `ruby setup.rb`

Comment: Looks like this answer is not the best route; but I will leave it up on the off chance it helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

It is showing that you don't have permission to write something in that directory. Instead, use this directory :

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

It works perfectly for me.

**(I am using macOS Sierra, version 10.12.6)**

Comment: I would highly suggest against using the system ruby and sudo.

Answer (score 0):

In the case when you see an older version of ruby in the directory that it's trying to access and **you have a fresh install** you can remove the ruby version folder in .gem directory in your home folder. For me it was `~/.gem/ruby/2.4.1/`. Gem will automatically detect the new version (that you can install both using brew or rbenv) and act accordingly.

This will remove all gems hovewer so keep that in mind.