# ionic 3 cannot add onesignal-cordova-plugin into ios platform. Error: rbenv: pod: command not found

Tags: ios, plugins, ionic3, onesignal

I am trying to integrate onesignal to ios. when i execute the command

> ionic cordova platform add ios

it fails with the following:

```
Discovered plugin "onesignal-cordova-plugin" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "onesignal-cordova-plugin" for ios

Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': undefined

Failed to restore plugin "onesignal-cordova-plugin" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: rbenv: pod: command not found

The `pod' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.1.2
```

Here is excerpts of my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.app.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
...
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^1.3.4" />
    <plugin name="onesignal-cordova-plugin" spec="^2.2.5" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="~4.5.4" />
</widget>
```

Comment: can you run `cordova requirements` command in your project folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install cocoapods for using OneSignal SDK with IOS platform. Check the documentation [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v4.0/docs/troubleshooting-cordova-variants#section-plugin-install-failure)

Do:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
pod repo update
```

Suggest you go through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381360/how-do-i-install-ruby-gems-on-mac) in case Ruby Gems is not installed.