# auto-generating list of figures and list of tables in asciidoctor

Tags: asciidoctor

The Asciidoctor official page says to gem-install asciidoctor-lists but it goes error as below:

gem install asciidoctor-lists
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory

Can anyone help about the resolution/workaround?

gem install asciidoctor-lists
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install ruby gems on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381360/how-do-i-install-ruby-gems-on-mac)