# installing gem in terminal on Mac gives permissions error

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rubygems

I tried to install a gem with `gem install test-unit` and get the same error each time.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0 directory.
```

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.7`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/). Then retry your `gem install` operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599889/error-while-executing-gem-gemfilepermissionerror

Comment: @JoshBrody The top voted answer is wrong as pointed out by the comments, and it's not really a duplicate as the linked question had a broken RVM installation and this user has system Ruby only.

Comment: You either `sudo gem install` or use an `rbenv` or RVM provided personal Ruby.