# How do I fix FilePermissions error when installing Cocoapods gem

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, flutter, cocoapods

I use Flutter and I want to test my app on an iPhone emulator or on an iPhone. I get the error to install Cocoapods.
When I try to install Cocoapods I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /usr/bin directory.
```

Comment: You have to have "root" permission, i.e. to be super user: please execute:  sudo gem install cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

Using the default Ruby install will require you to use sudo when installing gems. (This is only an issue for the duration of the gem installation, though.)

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

If you encounter any problems during installation, please visit [this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting#installing-cocoapods) guide.

**But the best practice is Never install gems with sudo**

Comment: Okay. Try adding eval "$(rbenv init -)" at the end of your .bash_profile. If that file doesn't exist in your home directory, create it. Then open a new shell and try the doctor again. Should be working!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599889/error-while-executing-gem-gemfilepermissionerror/25716203#25716203

Comment: Thanks. Iam not that. much into the macOS basics so how do i create it ore which file type should it be?