# Rails HTTParty shutsdown server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am sending an ajax request to a controller where httparty retrieves information from a server.  The problem I am having is when I send the ajax post request to the controller the local webbrick server shuts down. I am getting a segmentation fault error.  Any idea what the problem is?

Gist: https://gist.github.com/3802531

Comment: Please add the stacktrace you're seeing, probably best to use a pastebin, like [github gists](https://gist.github.com).

Comment: I haave sometimes such problem with other gems. But everything works good again after reinstalling such gem. I think It can be rvm bug.

Comment: Do you see the same crash when not using webrick? I always recommend using whichever server you deploy in production in your local environment. Webrick is pretty awful, honestly, and I don't recommend anyone to use it for anything.

Comment: I've tried thin. It still crashes.

Comment: Trying this now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540155/rails-segmentation-fault-on-mac-osx-with-rvm

Comment: This seems to stop the thin server from crashing: rvm pkg install openssl
rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$rvm_path/usr